# d3 Version4 getting null object

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to get d3 v4 to work basic simple rendering as v3 worked before, I'm getting null object. 
Here's a simple version of the code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.4.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var dataset = [23, 45, 66, 77, 88, 99];
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr({width: 500, height: 500});
    console.log('svg : '+svg);
</script>
```

Result of the above code is:

> svg : null

Writing the same code with v3, the result

> svg : [object SVGSVGElement]'

What am I missing here? I'm following the tutorials and most of them are in v3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `attr` function can take two arguments - the attribute name and the attribute value. Try this instead:

```
var dataset = [23, 45, 66, 77, 88, 99];
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("height", 500)
    .attr("width", 500);

console.log('svg : '+svg);
```

Comment: I just tried that and it works.. so I cant put all my attributes in one object? Do i have to specify one by one using the .attr() method?

Comment: That's correct. You can find more info about how to use selections here: https://github.com/d3/d3-selection

Comment: You are right. I just found this addressed here: https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/2907 and used the library https://github.com/d3/d3-selection-multi you mentioned and that worked. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

Despite all answers (including the current accepted answer) saying otherwise, you **can** pass an object to `attr` and `style` in D3 version 4.x, as long as:

- First, you reference "selection-multi":

  ```
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v1.min.js"></script>
  ```
- Second, you use `attrs` and `styles`, as a plural:

  ```
  d3.select("body").append("div")
       .attrs({
          title: "A cheery, timeless greeting.",
          class: "greeting"
       })
      .text("Hello, world!");
  ```

So, in your code, it should be:

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attrs({width: 500, height: 500});
```

Here is a demo to show you that **it works**:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attrs({width: 500, height: 500});
    
console.log('svg : ' +JSON.stringify(svg));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v1.min.js"></script>
```